# Why CLion don't put Spaces automatically when I finish a line with semicolon?

Tags: styles, editor, settings, clion, spaces

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a=0;
    double b=25.8;
    char *s="Hello!";
    int a2=45;
    if(a==a2){
        printf("No!");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It looks just like above, it should be spaces before and after "=" or "==".
But in Jetrains Rider, it works fine, I don't know why CLion cannot.
I think my setting is right, I don't even change it.

[My Code Style setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pot1G.png)

Answer (score 0):

In order to re-format your code press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.

You can also find this option under, `Code -> Reformat Code`.

Another option is to configure clang formatting so that your code gets formatted during build. You can find some information on how to setup clang formatting for a CMake project here:

[Add cppcheck and clang-format for a cmake project](https://arcanis.me/en/2015/10/17/cppcheck-and-clang-format)